# TomEE Maven Plugin does not log exception

Tags: java, apache, maven, plugins, apache-tomee

I encounter an issue with my fresh tomee instance. I created a maven tomee project with following code :

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.openejb.maven -DarchetypeArtifactId=tomee-webapp-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.7.2
```

I created a Servlet, override doGet method and just add

```
throw new IOExcepetion("this is a test");
```

And start my server like this

```
mvn package tomee:run
```

If I try to access to this servlet by web browser I can see the exception inside browser but nothing is logged inside the maven console.

How can I change my configuration in order to log exceptions thrown by tomee server ?

Thank a lot

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `<simpleLog>` parameter in the POM?

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.openejb.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>...</version>
  <configuration>
    <simpleLog>true</simpleLog>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

`<simpleLog>` is turned off by default.

Comment: Unfortunately I can see more log but my exception isn't logged